# VB.net Login with MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I do not know what went wrong. Im new to vb. Can someone help me? Maybe correct my codes cause I've been spending so much time with this login form of mine. Thanks! here's my code.
By the way, I have a table with 3 columns. Username, Password and Privilege. Whenever I input my Login credentials, it only display the Msgbox Try again.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class LoginForm
    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataAdapter

    Private Sub OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
        Dim tblUser As New DataTable

        Try
            If PasswordTextBox.Text = "" Or UsernameTextBox.Text = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide your login credentials!")
            Else
                Dim sql As String
                sql = "SELECT * from user_account where username = '" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and password = '" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'"

                Using con As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
                    With cmd
                        .Connection = con
                        .CommandText = sql
                    End With

                    reader.SelectCommand = cmd
                    reader.Fill(tblUser)

                    If tblUser.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        Dim userType As String
                        userType = tblUser.Rows(0).Item(2)

                        If userType = "admin" Then
                            MsgBox("Welcome, Admin!")
                            frmAdminMain.Show()
                        ElseIf userType = "encoder" Then
                            MsgBox("Welcome, User!")
                            MainForm.Show()
                        End If
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Invalid Credentials!")
                    End If
                    reader.Dispose()
                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Try Again!")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the "New" key word to your command declaration

```
 Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
```

"With" just set the properties, it does not initialize the object.

Comment: Am i just going to paste MsgBox(ex.ToString) in the catch part?

Comment: It says, System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at WindowsApplication1...vb:line 19

And the line 19 is .Connection = con

Comment: what am i gonna do? Do i have to declare my con as connection?

Comment: You were missing the initialization